# yfinance not returning todays intraday one minute bars

Tags: yfinance

This code returns 1 minute data for the last seven days, but it only returns a single quote for today. Is there a way to get the 1 minute bar data for today?

```
import yfinance as yf

from datetime import datetime, timedelta
x=datetime.now()
date_N_days_ago = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=7)
print(date_N_days_ago)
msft = yf.Ticker("MSFT")
data_df = yf.download("MSFT",start=date_N_days_ago.strftime("%Y"+"-"+"%m"+"-"+"%d"), interval="1m", end=x.strftime("%Y"+"-"+"%m"+"-"+"%d"))

data_df.to_csv('ds.csv')
```

Answer (score 1):

By default yfinance takes `period='max'` as parameter.
To get only last day or intraday during opening times you have to specify this parameter on your own.
In your case:

```
data_df = yf.download("MSFT",start=date_N_days_ago.strftime("%Y"+"-"+"%m"+"-"+"%d"), interval="1m", end=x.strftime("%Y"+"-"+"%m"+"-"+"%d"))
```

Just open the function for more details.
This is possible values for `period` - always depending on your `interval` value

```
period : str
            Valid periods: 1d,5d,1mo,3mo,6mo,1y,2y,5y,10y,ytd,max
            Either Use period parameter or use start and end
```

For example `period='6m', interval='1d'` is the maximum yahoo delivers with 1d candles